# await Firebase.initializeApp(); PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

i tried to connect my project to firebase but when connecting there is always an error message like this
[error message like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JClKk.png)

I have also used the latest packages but the problem remains the same
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkcEG.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the entire app, then run:

flutter clean

flutter pub get

then run it again.

Answer (score -1):

This error happens when there is a problem with the connection to the Firebase servers. Make sure:

1. You have correctly configured your Firebase project and added the necessary credentials to your app.
2. Clean the app using: flutter clean and remove pubspec.lock
3. Rebuild the app
4. If still facing the issue then restart your system

Comment: I've tried it and still the same error

Comment: Hi! Any news about this? I''m facing the same issue :( Everything updated, lock files (pubspeck and podfile) removed and re-added, too

Comment: the same issue with classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0' in dependencies. returning back to 4.3.14 helps me